# How to use a 'WHEN' clause in a MySQL Trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Print_salary_changes
  BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON Emp_tab
  FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.Empno > 0)
DECLARE ..
```

The above code works for oracle database but it won't work in Mysql.

Answer (score 0):

`WHEN` for triggers is not supported by MySQL. See [create trigger syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html)

Instead you can add IF in the trigger body

```
BEGIN
    IF NEW.Empno > 0
       your logic here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this :

```
  BEGIN
    DECLARE v INT DEFAULT 1;

    CASE v
      WHEN 2 THEN SELECT v;
      WHEN 3 THEN SELECT 0;
      ELSE
        BEGIN
        END;
    END CASE;
  END;
```

Comment: Please never post "try like this" answers on Stack Overflow.  Every answer should include an explanation which intends to educate/empower the OP and thousands of future researchers.